# Javascript If/Else giving incorrect return answer

Tags: javascript

I have the below code for a practice problem. Can someone explain why the correct output is not given in the original try where I use 'else' vs the second where I do not?

Original Answer:

```
function openSesame(array, str) {
  for (var i in array) {
    if (array[i] === str) {
      return 'You may pass.';
    } else {
      return 'You shall not pass!';
    }
  }
}
```

Correct answer:

```
function openSesame(array, str) {
  for (var i in array) {
    if (array[i] === str) {
      return 'You may pass.';
    }
  }
  return 'You shall not pass!';
}
```

For reference:

```
var passwords = [
  'Password123',
  'DavidYangsMiddleName',
  'qwerty',
  'S3cur3P455WORD',
  'OpenSesame',
  'ChildhoodPetsName',
  'Gandalf4evaa'
];

INPUT: openSesame(passwords, 'Password123');
OUTPUT: 'You may pass.'
INPUT: openSesame(passwords, 'Balrog');
OUTPUT: 'You shall not pass!'
```

Comment: In the original you `return` regardless of the value of your `if/then`. This makes the `for` loop only run once.

Answer (score 0):

Because having the `else` there covers all possibilities (either the current item is equal to the given string or it isn't), which means it will terminate the loop in the first iteration.

This means that the function will only give a correct answer if the first item in the array is equal to the string. For all other possibilities, it will return `"You shall not pass"`.

```js
function openSesame(array, str) {
  for (var i in array) {
    // at this point, if array[i] is equal to str
    // we will return "You may pass"
    // if not, we will return "You shall not pass"
    // Since this check happens on the first item
    // and we return some result no matter what
    // no other item will be reached
    if (array[i] === str) {
      return 'You may pass.';
    } else {
      return 'You shall not pass!';
    }
  }
}

var passwords = ['Password123', 'DavidYangsMiddleName', 'qwerty', 'S3cur3P455WORD', 'OpenSesame', 'ChildhoodPetsName', 'Gandalf4evaa'];

passwords.forEach(pw => {
  console.log(`openSesame(passwords, "${pw}") = "${openSesame(passwords, pw)}"`)
})
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: @a12m12 no problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is equivalent to:

```
const i = Object.keys(array)[0];

if (array[i] === str) {
    return 'You may pass.';
} else {
    return 'You shall not pass!';
}
```

That's why it won't look at other values